# Custom Auth form fields in cakephp 2.4.0

Tags: cakephp, authentication, authorization

I have my AuthComponent set up as an array in my AppController. I am using Form Authentication, and in the "fields" field of my "Form" array I currently have

```
array ('username' => 'email_address', 'password' => 'password'),
```

just like in most of the examples, and it appears to work just fine.

The problem is that I need to get the user data from the Auth object. When I call

```
$this->Auth->user ();
```

it returns an array with email_address and password set, exactly as I might expect. But I also need it to return the user ID, which is in a column called "id" in my users table. I tried adding 'id' => 'id' to my fields array, but that did nothing. I also tried 'user_id' => 'id' and 'userid' => 'id', but nothing worked.

Is there a way to get the Auth object to give me a little more information about the user than just the username and password? Or do I need to run a second query to do it?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing there (you should post more code, not just the one single array declaration), but if your user is logged in with a normal login precedure, you got the whole user data array in your session - hence access to all fields including the id.

Comment: Please post you database table for users